# How do I get the number of Twitter search results?

Tags: twitter

Twitter only shows me a list of Tweets that match my search criteria. I don't know if it is the whole list or if it is just some hard-coded limit of search results (like 1000 for Google). How can I find the *number* of Tweets that match my search criteria? (or am I just blind? :)

Answer (score 1):

the regular search.twitter.com limit used to arround 1500 a day

And

The search api used to be restricted to a limit of 150 tweets. And a year ago it was also restricted This limit is currently around 1.5 weeks but is dynamic and subject to shrink as the number of tweets per day continues to grow.